# How to use reverse proxy on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx, server

I have a single Server which is running on Port 3000. Now there is a problem that when I will do the heavy calculation with my MongoDB collection at that time if request coming from frontend then frontend user have to wait until backend process is executed. I thought about the two servers, that one is processing a request for frontend and another one is for Do heavy calculation with MongoDB.
What I Implemented for a single server is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_db_name', { useMongoClient: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
//Initialize App
var app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');

//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'shhhhh',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  cookie:{maxAge: 86400000},// For 24 hour
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db })
}));

//Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server Started on Port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

so what are the things I have to add to running multiple Instances on a different port?

Comment: Even if you do the heavy work in another app (app B), the frontend needs to wait till that work is completed, isn't it?

Comment: Currently, I am facing this Issue. That's the reason I will Make Different Server. One for User handling and another for Handling the Backend heavy calculation which are done through Cron Job

Comment: But not Able to Identify that How I can create This. I also investigating about Nginx reverse Proxy, But not able to implement as there is not a good Instruction From scratch to implement Nginx to Nodejs

Comment: So you have two systems. Sys 1 does the heavy load, running on a cron job. Sys 2 acts as the interface to the rest of the world. When a request comes for data, hy can't Sys 2 communicate with Sys 1 and fetch the data (which are already processed by Sys 1) and return that to client? Why do you need a reverse proxy here?